# How to replace a line using sed command after first occurence?

Tags: sed

I am using sed command to replace line after first occurence of the keyword.
I am using following command to replace whole line when i found keyword.

```
sed -i "/<port>/c<port>=$a" /root/output.txt
```

But my file is like

```
<namenode>
   <port>8080</port>
</namenode>
<derby>
   <port>5050</port>
</derby>
```

in  this case if i run above command it will change the both lines port of namenode and port of derby also. but
I want to change specific line . I will search for first occurrence of `<port>` after `<namenode>` , so it will change only namenode's port value not derby's port value.
and i am changing whole line by using above command.
I hope i will get answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you only want to change the port in the section called `namenode`.  In that case:

```
sed -i "/<namenode>/,/<\/namenode>/ s/<port>[0-9]\+/<port>$a/" /root/output.txt
```

The use of `/<namenode>/,/<\/namenode>/` restricts the operation of the replacement command to groups of lines whose first line contains  `<namenode>` and whose last line contains `</namenode>`.  Within that range, any port number is replaced with the value of the shell variable `$a`.

Comment: same concept as you :-)

Comment: it's working only when <namenode> <port>  but suppose i have some lines in between <namenode> and <port> i.e <namenode> <second> sakdma <port> then it's not replacing the text

Comment: @sandy_ws I just tried that example and, even with the intervening lines, it works for me.  If the problem persists for you, please make available, maybe in the body of the question, an exact copy of exact file that is causing problems along with whatever error messages might appear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using `awk`

```
a=9090
awk '/<namenode>/ {f=1} f && /<port>/ {$0="   <port>"new"</port>";f=0}1' new="$a" file
<namenode>
   <port>9090</port>
</namenode>
<derby>
   <port>5050</port>
</derby>
```

It will only change the `port` after `namenode` to the value stored in variable `a`

---

How it works:

```
awk '
/<namenode>/ {                  # If the line contains "<namenode>"
    f=1}                        # do set flag `f` to `1` (true)
f && /<port>/ {                 # If flag `f` is true and line contains "<port>"
    $0="   <port>"new"</port>"  # change line to new data
    f=0}                        # and reset flag `f`
1                               # Do default action (print the line)
' new=10 file                   # Read variable and the file
```

---

Using the range function:

```
awk '/<namenode>/,/<\/namenode>/ {if (/<port>/) $0="   <port>"new"</port>"}1' new="$a" file
```

Comment: i was only using sed for but first time tried with awk...awesome thank you.

Comment: HI Jotne after replacing the value it just printing on console...how to change it in file.

Comment: @sandy_ws  You do like this to replace in file: `awk 'code' file > tmp && mv tmp file`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i "/^<namenode>/,/<\/namenode>/ {
   /<port>/c<port>=$a
   }" /root/output.txt
```

Encapsulate into another block